# Why react native admob not working in RN<57.8

Tags: react-native, admob

react-native-admob not working in my RN < 57.8 app

I tried :

```
npm install react-native-admob@next --save

npm install @types/react-native-admob

npm i react-native-admob -S

npm install

react-native link
```

declare module 'react-native-admob'

updated tools to 28.0.3

```js
import {  AdMobBanner  } from 'react-native-admob';
    
    
export default class Intro extends React.Component {
  bannerError(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground style={{width:'100%',height:'100%',}} source=      {require('../assets/start1.jpg')}>
          <AdMobBanner
            bannerSize="fullBanner"
            adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
            testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
            didFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} />
        </ImageBackground >
       </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**Error**

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-admob'.
>   'e:/react/almustaqbal/node_modules/react-native-admob/index.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install
>   @types/react-native-admob` if it exists or add a new declaration
>   (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-admob';`ts(7016)

Comment: While editing I noticed your code had `<Container />` closing tag misspelled hope you correct that on your code too also I think installing `react-native-admob` & `react-native-admob@next` is just installing the same thing in different versions which might result in unintended issues while importing, so try to remove one *I suggest the @next one* and link.

Comment: still having same error , also i tried new project and installed only                      npm i react-native-admob -S & react-native link   still same error

Answer (score 1):

After trying numerous times i guess **react-native-admob** isn't working in **RN<57.8**

So i found another way working in RN<57.8 is :

**react-native-firebase**

i found this web for good explanation https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-firebase-admob/